# Sort array of object pointers

Tags: c++, sorting, pointers, access-violation, stl-algorithm

I'm learning about inheritance in college, I was given an assignment to create an array of Product pointers (base class) and fill it with Software or Book objects (derived classes)

I did all this with no problems (bar the slicing problem we are supposed to get)

After the array has been filled we have been asked to sort it in ascending order.

I did some research and decided to use the [std::sort() function](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/NhA0RXSz/)

My problem is I'm getting an access violation error, It's late and I'm tired, am I overlooking something obvious?

I've left out a lot of code, if I need to include anything to help with the solution let me know.

```
    bool wayToSort(Product *i, Product *j)
{
    return  i->getGrossPrice() < j->getGrossPrice();
}

int main(){

Product *prodPtr[10];

// Sort Product array
    std::sort(begin(prodPtr), end(prodPtr), wayToSort);


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        cout << "Gross price for prod " << i + 1 << ": " << prodPtr[i]->getGrossPrice() << endl;
    }
```

}

The access violation is in the getGrossPrice() function
Product.cpp

```
double  Product::getGrossPrice(){
    double grossPrice = (netPrice * 21 / 100) +  netPrice;
    return grossPrice;
}
```

Comment: You never created your Products. Maybe that's part of what you left out, but right now you just have an array of 10 pointers that point to nothing. Make sense? Use `new Product();`/`new Software();`/`new Book()` to create your products.

Comment: where is netPrice declared?

Comment: Here is my main http://ideone.com/yiD2aV netPrice is declared in my product class

Comment: You're invoking *undefined behavior*. I see *three* objects created in an array designed to point at *ten* of them, leaving seven indeterminate, and you trying to sort *all* of them (valid and invalid). Using `std::sort(prodPtr, prodPtr+3)` will likely work, but honestly a vector solution with either direct objects or smart pointers would be considerably more robust.

Comment: I had though about using vector, I think this would have been a better option, I was aware of only filling the array with 3, when the size was ten. I didn't want to have to enter 10 numbers each time, I see the error this may cause using begin(prodPtr), end(prodPtr) now, I'll adjust my code accordingly and see how I get on.